# I need to figure out SMB1 support on a fairly new HP Color LaserJet Pro

Tags: linux, scanning, multi-function-printer, hp

I have a fairly new HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M283cdw and after Samba dropped support for smb1 in 4.11, I am unable to use the fairly important "Scan to Network Folder" feature.

Aside from using a VM and installing an older version of Linux to use an older samba version, are there any known workarounds for this? I know there are security concerns with smb1 and WannaCry but I do not have any Windows devices on our home network at all.

I have the most current driver from the HP website. I saw a white paper on manuals.plus saying that they added support for smb2 & smb3 to the M280-281 printers, but not the M283. ("Reason Added HP Color LaserJet Pro M280-M281 MFP - Added to SMB2 and SMB3 support")

Before I go the VM route to use this rather important feature, I'm trying to see if anyone else has this same printer (bought it from Costco) and has run into this as well.

Edit: I have tried to get support from HP but they are not helpful, insisting that I need to update Windows. I do not have Windows here at all.

Comment: Even though it does not explicitly indicate support for SMBv3 have you tried?

Comment: If you are asking if I tried the firmware for the 280-281, I have, it's a different version and would not install on my device unfortunately.

Comment: Why don't you just downgrade the Samba version to one that does support SMBv1?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that as holding the release to one version can hold up other dependencies, but that may be the route that I have to take. It's on an ubuntu VM at the moment.

Comment: WannaCry has nothing to do with the SMBv1 _protocol,_ anyway – it was an exploit for Windows SMBv1 server code specifically. Nobody runs screaming about Apache's HTTP/1.1 support being dangerous whenever there's an IIS exploit, but somehow that keeps happening for SMB.

Comment: ["Solved" does not belong to the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310), a solution does not belong to the question. Accepting an answer is enough.

Comment: @user1686 Please elaborate, as one of major news stories ~2017 was SMBv1 being exploited on a SmartTV running Linux by a state agency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba still supports SMBv1, it is, like Windows 10, just turned off by default. You can turn it on again by adding two lines to your smb.conf:

client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1